# Copay cryptocurrency wallet attack: why did hackers rewrite module source file?

Tags: javascript, cryptocurrency

There was [the notorious attack](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/116) on the Copay cryptocurrency wallet in 2018. To recap it briefly, the JavaScript based wallet depended on a library, `event-stream`. Using social engineering, hackers gained ability to change this library and publish its new versions through `npm` package manager. Injected malicious code was intended to carry out the following things:

1. [Payload A](https://gist.github.com/jsoverson/3df90445adfca27341ed86426d69f87d#file-payloada-js) (a chunk of code) deciphers [Payload B](https://gist.github.com/jsoverson/3df90445adfca27341ed86426d69f87d#file-payloadb-js) and runs it with the aid of Node.js [`Module.prototype._compile`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e2a6399be742f53103474d9fc1e56fadf7f90ccc/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L1055) function. Payload B exports a function (with [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports)), which then gets executed. *(These code steps are given in much more convenient way in the first comment of the github issue)*.
2. This function objective was to inject yet another deciphered [Payload C](https://gist.github.com/jsoverson/3df90445adfca27341ed86426d69f87d#file-payloadc-js). Its code was introduced by means of [`writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) into `ReedSolomonDecoder.js` file, which in fact was a part of a lib dependency (of a module inside the `./node_modules` folder).
3. When someone calls [`require('./ReedSolomonDecoder.js')`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) for the first time, injected Payload 3, in turn, would call `require('bitcore-wallet-client/lib/credentials.js')` and fiddle with its function prototypes, so for now on user passwords would send to a hackers server.
4. When Node.js environment emits [`process.exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) event, `ReedSolomonDecoder.js` is returned to its initial state.

My question is why did the hacker opt for this involved and precarious way including OS file modifications? Instead, they could tinker with the `credentials.js` module immediately after the first injected code (Payload A) get execution. Can anybody at least *suggest* an explanation of such decision? My only thought is when the Payload A is run, `require('bitcore-wallet-client/lib/credentials.js')` was not yet been called and it was not safe for attackers to initiate its first call for some reasons.